# Is it possible in airflow to set trigger rule or each specific upstream?

Tags: airflow

Let say I have a BigqueryOperator

```
#example
task_operator = BigqueryOperator(
    dag=dag,
    table_name='bq_table$20220601',
    task_id='produce_bq_table',
    sql='sql/produce_bq_table.sql'
)
```

bq_table query depend on the availability of the tables below:

- fact_table_1
- fact_table_2
- dim_table_3

BigqueryCheckOperator to check the data of 3 tables above before running `produce_bq_table`.

```
#example
task_operator.set_upstream([
  check_fact_table_1,
  check_fact_table_2,
  check_dim_table_3
])
```

The default trigger rule for the BigqueryOperator is all_success.
Is it possible to have the pipeline run once the upstream are available but with the conditions below:

- check_fact_table_1: must success
- check_fact_table_2: either it is success or failed, once all the retries has done, next downstream can start
- check_dim_table_3: must success.

Afaik airflow have trigger rule all_done. But can we specify which upstream must success and which upstream can just done no matter what is the status?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is such option. But it seems the same result can be achieved by defining 2 dummy/empty operators d1 and d2 and setting up dependencies and trigger rules like this:

```
[t1, t3] >> d1 all_success
t2 >> d2 all_done
[d1, d2] >> produce_bq_table all_success
```